# get elements of an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have variable called `$data` some times this variable return helmets or return gloves from data in Excel and I have this associative array

```
$productCateegories = array ( "Helmets" => 30, "Gloves" => 20, "Helmet"=> 10);
```

I would like to check the `$data` variable against the array element in case that the data variable equals gloves then set another variable which is called `$data2` to 20.

Comment: Great! So what's your question?

Comment: how can I check that the $data variable which that is sometimes equals to gloves or helmets its value in the associative array list . so if $data equals gloves than set $data2 to 20 comparing or receiving the value from the associative list

Comment: `$productCategories[$data]` what's they problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
$productCateegories = array ( "Helmets" => 30, "Gloves" => 20, "Helmet"=> 10);
$data = 30;
```

Unlike indexes used in accessing array elements, associative array elements are accessed using the keys. In your case when comparing the associative array and `$data` variable you could try the code below.

```
$data2 = null;
//when checking if it's equal to "Gloves"
if($data == $productCateegories["Gloves"]){
    $data2 = $productCateegories["Gloves"];
    //do other things
}
//when checking if it's equal to "Helmets"
else if($data == $productCateegories["Helmets"]){
    $data2 = $productCateegories["Helmets"]; 
    //do other things
}
//when checking if it's equal to "Helmet"
else if($data == $productCateegories["Helmet"]){
    $data2 = $productCateegories["Helmet"]; 
    //do other things
}
```

Comment: how to set $data2 to its element for example for gloves $data2 should be equal to 20.

Comment: I want to set data2 from reading the numbers in the associative array

Comment: If $data is of type string as in the "Gloves" etc, then https://stackoverflow.com/a/51831188/10031106 gets you what you want otherwise $productCateegories["Gloves"] gives you the value 20 as I did in the code

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a concept called variable-variables.

Which can allow you to do:

```
${$data}Count=$productCategories[$data];
```

And then you can get helmetCount and gloveCount as:

```
echo $helmetCount;

echo $gloveCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work.

```
if (in_array($data, array_keys($productCateegories)) {
    // Do something if in array.
}
```

Otherwise you can also check like this, which will check if it's set, and then set the value.

```
if (isset(productCateegories[$data])) {
    $data2 = $productCateegories[$data];  // 20
}
```